# knockoutJS doesn't convert Json to observable

Tags: javascript, json, model-view-controller, knockout.js

I wrote a simple application to get JSON data from the sever
C# code
        public JsonResult Read()
        {
            var products = db.Products;
            return Json(GetProducts(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

```
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts()
    {
        var data = db.Products.ToList();
        return (data);
    }
```

In the view i wrote the following to bind view model data.

```
<div>
<table data-bind="with: products">
    <thead><tr><th>From</th><th>To</th><th>Subject</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Object">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: description"></td>
        </tr>    
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function ProductsViewModel() {
         var self = this;
         self.products = ko.observable();
         $.getJSON("http://localhost:50998/Home/Read", function (data) {
             self.products = JSON.parse(data);
         });

}
     ko.applyBindings(new ProductsViewModel());
 </script>
```

The Json data return from action is as follows

```
[{"ID":1,"Name":"Roger","Description":"Test1"},{"ID":2,"Name":"Roger2","Description":"Test2"}]
```

After i have parse the JSON, i can't use the parsed object to update the observerable.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set the value of `self.products` (or the value of any other observable) to the result of `JSON.parse` you need to call it like this `self.products(JSON.parse(data))`. Observables are like functions so you need to treat them like functions ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your help, you are right, however, even i change the code to         $.getJSON("http://localhost:50998/Home/Read", function (data) { 
             self.products(JSON.parse(data));
         });  it still doesn't work, is there any other problem with my code.

Comment: So you want to make each property of each item in your JSON a ko.observable? If yes I recommend using knockouts mapping plugin http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html this will do this for you.

Comment: Thanks, what i want is to follow the same sample in the knockoutjs learning get all the emails from the odata and binds to a list, but i wrote a action return JSON data, so i use $.getJSON to get the data, and bind to a list. In the tutorial, it doesn't need to bind all the property of each item, it just get the data and update the observable folder,and loop for each email. I will try the mapping pluging first and see if it is work.

Comment: You are loading an array from JSON, but passing it to an observable(). Although this would work, you should probably be using a knockout observeableArray()